# What happens to Travis' daughter?

Tags: continuum

In Continuum, Travis supposedly inducts his daughter in CPS's good books by letting her give him away. Is it safe to assume that in that timeline, she becomes a police officer in CPS and works for anti corporate fighters? Was there any further indication of what happened to her?

Did she go into further future and do something?